# When to prefer for-loop over std::transform or vice-versa

Tags: c++11, for-loop, stl

I would like to understand when it is more practical to use std::transform
and when an old fashioned for-loop is better.

This is my code with a for loop, I want to combine two vectors into a complex one:

```
    vector<double> vAmplitude = this->amplitudeData(N);
    vector<double> vPhase = this->phaseData(N);
    vector<complex<double>,fftalloc<complex<double> > > vComplex(N);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        vComplex[i] = std::polar(vAmplitude[i], vPhase[i]);
    }
```

This is my std::transform code

```
    vector<double> vAmplitude = this->amplitudeData(N);
    vector<double> vPhase = this->phaseData(N);
    vector<complex<double>,fftalloc<complex<double> > > vComplex;
    std::transform(
                begin(vPhase), end(vPhase), begin(vAmplitude),
                std::back_inserter(vComplex),
                [](double p, double a) { return std::polar(a, p); });
```

Note that vComplex is allocated without size, so I wonder when the allocations happends. Also I do not understand why, in the lambda expression, `p` and `a` must be reversed to their usage.

Comment: [This Going Native episode](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Cpp-Seasoning) comes to mind, where Sean Parent gives some examples of when to prefer the C++-standard library's algorithms over raw loop syntax.

Answer (score 17):

One consideration in favor of the standard algorithms, is that it prepares your code (and you) for the [c++17 alternative execution model versions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/parallelism/existing#transform).

To borrow from JoachimPileborg's answer, say you write your code as

```
vector<complex<double>,fftalloc<complex<double> > > vComplex(N);
std::transform(
    begin(vAmplitude), end(vAmplitude), begin(vPhase),
    std::begin(vComplex),
    std::polar);
```

After some time, you realize that this is the bottleneck in your code, and you need to run it in parallel. So, in this case, all you'd need to do is add
[`std::execution::par{}`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag) as the first parameter to `std::transform`. In the hand-rolled version, your (standard-compliant) parallelism choices are gone.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the allocation, that's what [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) does.

You could also set the size for the destination vector `vComplex` and use `std::begin` for it in the [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) call:

```
vector<complex<double>,fftalloc<complex<double> > > vComplex(N);
std::transform(
            begin(vPhase), end(vPhase), begin(vAmplitude),
            std::begin(vComplex),
            [](double p, double a) { return std::polar(a, p); });
```

As for the reversal of the arguments in the lambda, it's because you use `vPhase` as the first container in the [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) call. If you changed to use `vAmplitude` instead you could have passed just a pointer to `std::polar` instead:

```
std::transform(
            begin(vAmplitude), end(vAmplitude), begin(vPhase),
            std::begin(vComplex),
            std::polar);
```

Lastly as for *when* to call [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) it's more of a personal matter in most cases. I personally prefers to use [the standard algoritm functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) before trying to do everything myself.

Comment: The code compiles and works only with the lambda function, just using `std::polar`does not compile.